# Change the url for wordpress (image)attachment page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm having the following problem and can't find out how to fix it:

In Wordpress i use the attachment pages, which are auto generated when you add an image to a post/page. However the attachment page url is based on the page and subpages, which makes the url very long and not pretty.

how the attachment url looks now:

**domain.com/page/subpage1/subsubpage/image-title/**

I would like to change the url of these attachment pages to something more clean like:

**domain.com/media/image-title/**

How can i do this? is there a way to rewrite these urls?

Comment: See this answer on wordpress.stackexchange : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/is-there-a-user-facing-interface-to-edit-an-attachments-permalink

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that answer only allows you to change the name of the attachment, but not the url structure.